Creating a python function that sorts a list
Created a python function that takes a list and sorts out a list. However I don't get an output when I run the function with a list.
def sort1(w):
    my_sort =[]
    for num in w :
        min_num = w[0]
        if num < min_num:
            min_num = num
    my_sort = my_sort.append(min_num)
    w=w.remove(min_num)
    return my_sort


This is a bubble sort algorithm. But your implementation is not really efficient for at least 2 reasons: 1/ you append one element at a time to a list when you already know the final size, and 2/ you remove one element at a time from a list which is not a simple operation. Fine if you are doing that for learning Python language, but if you are learning algorithmics, you could try to post a fixed version on Code Review.

Not sure what you were trying to implement. You are adding just one number to your new list and also removing a number from the input list, which I think you should avoid. You should look for pseudo code of sorting algorithms so you can understand how they work. Your question makes it seem like your knowledge is very basic, so it's a good opportunity to build and extend it

@SergeBallesta Clearly no bubble sort, not even close.

I see what you're trying to do, but your code has some issues. Specifically, you're incorrectly using .append(), and remove() doesn't return the modified list. Here's a corrected version of your function:
def sort1(w):
    my_sort = []
    while w:
        min_num = w[0]
        for num in w:
            if num < min_num:
                min_num = num
        my_sort.append(min_num)
        w.remove(min_num)
    return my_sort

The while loop continues until the original list w is empty, picking out the minimum number in each pass.
Anyways, the same as what you want to do can be solved more efficiently and simply:
def sort1(w):
    return sorted(w)

This implementation is much faster, especially for larger lists.

Or eta-reduce to sort1 = sorted. But using sorted is almost certainly not what the assignment had in mind.
